# Excel VBA to Force Uppercase Messes Up Data in Table When Deleting Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA I found online that I use to ensure all data entered into a spreadsheet is uppercase, it is entered in the Worksheet Change VBA section for the sheet I want it to run on. The VBA works perfectly, but when I delete a column in the talbe, it copies the header of the column to the right and fills it all the way down overwriting everything already in that column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.HasFormula Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target = UCase(Target.Cells(1))
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I thought of trying to tie the running of the code to a cell (named Up_Case) that has data validation to only either be Yes or No, but could not seem to get the correct combination of If statements.

I am hoping there is an easier way to just modify the code to not ruin the table when modifying columns but if not then setting it up to only run when the named cell is "Yes" would work.

Not sure if it is relevant but the named cell is on another worksheet because the main worksheet gets printed by others ocasionally and they have issues if they see anything else on that worksheet.

Comment: Please share in detail what the code is supposed to do and at which moment. Also, adding a screenshot of your data would help to understand more clearly.

Comment: If Target is a multi-cell range then your code assigns the same (upper-cased) value to *all cells* in that range...  Presumably that's not the intent?  If you only want to handle single-cell updates then add `If Target.CountLarge>1 Then Exit sub` as the first line in the sub.

Comment: The worksheet is simply a list of parts we have offsite. The code is supposed to force data entered to be uppercase because it makes it easier to read on screen and when printed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code that Tim Williams put in the comments worked, so the updated code I have on the worksheet is now as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.HasFormula Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target = UCase(Target.Cells(1))
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would extracting the core logic from the event handlers and placing it in a separate location (module) for improved maintainability. This ensures that you won't have to sift through various objects to locate the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   ConvertRangeToUppercase Target
End Sub


Sub ConvertRangeToUppercase(ByVal TargetRange As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    ' Avoid formulas or entire rows or columns
    If TargetRange.HasFormula Or TargetRange.Rows.Count = Rows.Count Or TargetRange.Columns.Count = Columns.Count Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Cell In TargetRange
        Cell.Value = UCase(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```